# Excel: get row from criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, row, vlookup, transpose

I have one Excel file with two sheets. The first sheets contains data (Events with date and more information in columns), and in the second sheet I want to display Events from one sort of category and if they are in the future.

I tried various aproaches, but could't work it out at all. First I tried to **transose** the data from the first sheet, which made me realize was a bad approach, then I tried **Vlookup** which seems to be the best approach, but even after 6 tutorials I couldn't make it work to get the whole row, where the Category is "Walk Up".

To display a list with all "Walk Up" Events would be one first good step. After that I will have to check if the date for the events has been expired would be the second.

**Criteria:**

- Event has EventType: "Walk Up"
- Event has date > today
  ==> Get all Events matching the criteria

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you have a data setup like this:

[[image: enter image description here]]

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to create a helper column.  In this example, we'll use column D.  We'll also setup the criteria you want to pull by having those as sort of criteria information over your result set.  It'll end up looking this this:

[[image: enter image description here]]

So to get it to look like that, I did the following:

- Put this formula in your helper column (in this case cell D2 and copied down): `=IF(AND(A2=$G$1,B2>$G$2),MAX(D$1:D1)+1,"")`
- Put this formula in cell F5 and copy down: `=IF(ROW(F1)>MAX(D:D),"",$G$1)`
- Put this formula in cell G5 and copy over and down: `=IF($F5="","",INDEX($A:$C,MATCH(ROW(G1),$D:$D,0),MATCH(G$4,$1:$1,0)))`

At this point you can hide the helper column if preferred, and if you want your results on a different sheet, just cut and paste to a different sheet (in this case you'd cut columns F:H).